# issues faced while converting jupyter notebook to script

Tags: python, python-3.7, fast-ai

I had a jupyter notebook which I converted to script using the `nbconvert`. I am facing a few issues here. The code uses fastai.

1. The output of the `fit_one_cycle` function consists of table. while running the script I am getting this message instead of the table. `<IPython.core.display.HTML object>`. I imported the package `from IPython.core.display import display, HTML`, but the message still exists.
2. The confusion matrix is not showing.

   ```
   interp.plot_confusion_matrix(figsize=(4,4), dpi=60, normalize=True)
   plt.show()
   ```

There no plot in the terminal can this be corrected?